# Html5 canvas clickable ONLY on pre-existing line and add a Dot on click

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, haxe

I am having trouble finding a good method to limit my mouse to be only able to click on a pre existing line in canvas (stroke width of 3)

What I need to know

1. how to limit mouse so can only click on pre- existing line, add a dot on click

line is drawn with this function

```hx
function createLine(startX:Float, startY:Float, endX:Float, endY:Float)
{    
    surface.beginPath();
    surface.moveTo(startX, startY);
    surface.lineTo(endX, endY);
    surface.closePath();
    surface.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
    surface.lineWidth = 2;
    surface.stroke();
}
```

I am working in haxe, but solution in JS is fine

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is for you to keep track of what you have drawn and do the collision/mouse over detection on your own.

If you need your canvas to be highly interactive, you should probably be looking at SVG. http://raphaeljs.com/ is a great library for drawing which will use canvas or SVG, whichever is available.